# clearTimeout inside an Event Handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm detecting a scroll end with clearTimeout.

```
   const Component= ({container}) => {
      const timeoutRef = useRef<number>(0)
    
      const handleScroll = {
         clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
         timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(function () {
            if(!timeoutRef.current){ // 'no scroll in progress, do something' }
         }, 100)
      }

    useEffect(() => {
        container.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true)
    }, [])
    
}
```

But the timeoutRef is not reset when scrolling again, instead, its value only increases. How to fix that?

Comment: `!timeoutRef.current)` UM you do not remove the value anywhere so why would it ever go into that if? If that setTimeout fires, that means the scrolling did stop.

Answer (score 1):

That is how setTimeout works. Every time you generate a timeout it generates a new identifier. You use that identifier to cancel the timeout. The timeout does not clear the variable.

If the setTimeout fires, that means it was not cancelled. In your case that means the user did stop scrolling.

```
 timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('User is done scrolling');
 }, 100)
```

Comment: @espascarello, Thank you, what value should I use in order to check if scrolling is running/stopped?

Comment: You would need to set something in setTimeout